# Best practices for bulk updating old data

Tags: trigger, batch, bestpractice, data-migration

I have a new trigger that fires whenever I add/update a Contact.  Let's say it calls a method in class which sets the Contact's `X1337_Name__c` field to a l33t h4X0r3d (that is, 'leet haxored') version of their full name.  It doesn't matter what the trigger does.

Anyway, I already have 50k Contacts in my org, and my code or my users depend on this `X1337_Name__c` field being accurate.

One approach is to add another class (one that implements `Batchable<Contact>`) and, on deployment, run that bulk job.  Is that the best approach?  Is there another?  Can I just call the trigger more directly?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use batch classes to update your contacts, the other approach would be to use Developer console and run anonymous code snippets like below

```
String lastExecutedId='';
String objectQuery = 'select X1337_Name__c from Contact';
List<Contact> updateContacts = new List<Contact>();

if(!String.isBlank(lastExecutedId))
  objectQuery += ' Where ID> \''+ lastExecutedId+'\'';  

objectQuery += ' ORDER BY ID Limit 50000';

Boolean notBlankFlag =False;
   fOR(Contact con : (List<Contact>)Database.query(objectQuery)){

       con.X1337_Name__c ='abc'; //Whatever you want to do here

       updateContacts.add(con);

       //We can insert 10k record in a single go, however sometimes that  can reusult in time out exception, as everything is getting executed in a synchronous manner. You can reduce this below limit if there are many dependant workflows, trigger execution on contact
       if(updateContacts.size()==10000){ 
           lastExecutedId=con.id;
           break;
       }

   }

List<Database.saveresult> results = database.update(updateContacts, false);

Integer index=0;
List<String> errorIds = new List<String>();
for(Database.saveresult sr : results){
    if (!sr.isSuccess()) {  
        errorIds.add(updateContacts[index].id);
    } 
    index++;
}
System.debug('Total Errors - '+errorIDs.size());
system.debug('Error IDs ->'+errorIDs);
System.debug('Please copy this id for next execution -----> '+lastExecutedId);
```

Copy the lastExecutedID from your debug log and update it in the next execution.

Note: Sometimes Salesforce skips some part of debug log. In that scenario directly query the id using Query Execute

```
[Select id From Contact Limit 10000 Order by ID DESC]
```

And just the copy the first ID and update the code. I am assuming you are smart enough to update this number to 20k in next execution and keep updating.

To prevent recursion using Static variables:

I will update my recursion class to include a list of IDs for current trigger execution and will flush them if a new insert is executed, by checking if triggersIDs DOES NOT contain new IDs. If I am inserting/updating a related contact, I would simply add related ID in the Set.

```
Public Class RecursionPreventionClass{
    Public Static Boolean isFirstInsert;
    Public Static Set<ID> triggerIDs;
}
```

**This approach will fail if you go for COMPLEX Scenarios.** Otherwise go for Batch classes.

Comment: a coda to this approach (as I just did something like this the other day) - if the DML involves triggers and those triggers use static variables to prevent recursive invocation, the triggers won't do anything on record 201 and beyond.  This is because anonymous apex transaction is much broader in scope than Data Loader or batch class.  This issue is particularly true if the trigger reinvocation guard is a simple Boolean rather than a map of IDs

Comment: I have updated my code to include some testing for static variables. You will have to update your triggers or handler classes a bit to accommodate this. Note again this is not a full proof code, just a workaround if you don't want batch classes.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-time deal, I would also run a script through the Developer Console instead of creating new classes.

I would add a new checkbox field in contact (temporarily) called "NameUpdated__c". Make sure the default is false.

Then, simply, run this via the developer console a few times (likely about 5)

```
List<Contact> conts = [select Id, Name from Contact where NameUpdated__c = false limit 10000];

for (Contact cont : conts) {
  //Make sure that this update will fire your trigger (it may be expecting changes to the "Name" field only)
  cont.NameUpdated__c = true; 
}

database.update(conts, false);
```

I have not included any error handling here, so ensure that your trigger works fine before launching this. After running this 5-6 times (depending on the # of contacts you have) you can query the "NameUpdated__c" field to see which contacts failed to update and must be manually fixed.